# Gold cost to respec skills

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

Trying to find information on the skill reset available using in-game gold (not crown points), most of the sources indicate a cost of *100 gold per allocated skill point* however others say it depends on player level.

What is the relation of gold cost / skill point with player progression, or is it always a fixed value? Also, do we need to reset **all** skills or is it now possible to reset only unwanted skills?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It costs **50 gold per skill point** to respec skills at the *Shrine of Stendarr*. There is also a seperate option to only remove morphs, for the same 50g/SP.

Note that you must reset **all** morphs or skills, not just the ones that are unwanted (and accordingly, pay the amount for all those SP that are reset).